# Как создать функцию маршрутизации по URL?

Tags: php, функции

Всегда делал так в index.php

```
<?php

  // Если главная страница
  if ($url == '/') {
     require('templates/pageMain.php');
  }

  // Если страница категории
  elseif (preg_match ('|^/category/([0-9]+)$|', $url, $var)) {
     require('templates/pageCategory.php');
  }

  // Если страница статьи
  elseif (preg_match ('|^/article/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$|', $url, $var)) {
     require('templates/pageArticle.php');
  }

  // Если страницы не существует
  else {
     require('templates/404.php');
  }

?>
```

Кто может показать решение проще и изящнее? А то когда 200 шаблонов страниц, получается слишком большая обойма регулярок.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$routes = array (
    '|^/$|' => 'templates/pageMain.php',
    '|^/category/([0-9]+)$|' => 'templates/pageCategory.php',
    '|^/article/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$|' => 'templates/pageArticle.php',
    '|^.|' => 'templates/404.php'
);
foreach ($routes as $regexp => $route)
{
    if (preg_match ($regexp, $url, $var))
    {
        require ($route);
        exit;
    }
}
```

?>

Писал на коленке, на работоспособность не проверял. Думаю суть тут ясна ;) 404 страница должна быть последней в массиве она срабатывает вконце, когда другие условия не сработали. Както так ...

Answer (score 0):

Почему бы просто не выкусывать первую часть пути и по этой части подгружать соответствующий шаблон?

```
// Если главная страница
if ($url == '/') {
  $file = 'templates/pageMain.php';
} elseif (preg_match ('|^/(\w+)/|', $url, $var)) {
  $file = 'templates/page' . ucfirst($var[1][0] . '.php');
} else
  $file = '';

if (file_exists($file))
  require($file);
else {
  require('templates/404.php');
}
```

Comment: Не подходит, так как в вашем примере работает одна регулярка на все урлы, а у меня урлы могут быть абсолютно разные,  /news  /news-473, /news-473-41 и т.д. Я думаю в сторону функции, где я буду передавать урл и функция будет проверять что-то в стиле. если есть числовой айди то значит нужно даже незнаю что нужно =(

Comment: Моя функция подходит под тот вопрос, что Вы задали. У меня нет телепатических способностей и я не могу угадать, что же у Вас еще может быть

Comment: Как ваша функция в отличии от моего примера способна обработать url адреса вида page/1/ и page/1/2 и просто page ? Возможно я чего-то не понял, но функция не универсальна даже для моего случая, который приведен в примере. В моем примере разные шаблоны грузятся по разным правилам preg_match, в вашем же менять правила preg_match нельзя, не гибко.